# iOS app builds successfully but simulator does not run

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I'm running the following tutorial for developing RestKit applications -> https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md.

I have advanced to this step -> "You should now be able to build & run the app via the Product > Run menu (or hit Apple+R). The application should start as expected and show you an empty table view similar to the following".

My workspace builds successfully but the simulator does not start.  I have put an NSLog statement in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions: and that log statement is not displayed.

I have done multiple single project tutorials and they have all built and run successfully.  This is the first tutorial that I am attempting with builds a workspace with CocoaPods and includes third party components such as AFNetworking and RestKit.  I have researched the issue on the other posts on this topic on StackOverflow and have been unable to correct the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I have noticed... that on my laptop the simulator simply takes a while (sometimes a couple minutes) to actually open after the "build is successful", while on my workplace terminal, it lights up right away.

Comment: Yes, mine can take as long as 30 seconds sometimes to come to the front.  But in this case the Stop button is greyed out and it never starts.  There is no icon for it in the dock.  I've opened an Apple Tech ticket.  It will be interesting to see what is causing it.